# I am trying to instal HDF5 on my windows 10 64-bit computer.

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, hdf5, h5py, pythonxy

I have python(x,y) and am trying to install h5py. however the error I receive is 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wa42hjf9\h5py\

when I run:
pip install h5py

Then is says:

Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-2.6.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc.build'

```
Installed c:\users\yaady\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-rawecmvd\pkgconfig-1.1.0\.eggs\nose-1.3.7-py3.5.egg
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

Installed c:\users\yaady\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-wa42hjf9\h5py\.eggs\pkgconfig-1.1.0-py3.5.egg
Searching for Cython>=0.19
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/Cython/
Best match: Cython 0.24.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/c6/fe/97319581905de40f1be7015a0ea1bd336a756f6249914b148a17eefa75dc/Cython-0.24.1.tar.gz#md5=890b494a12951f1d6228c416a5789554
Processing Cython-0.24.1.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dhfiv996\Cython-0.24.1\setup.cfg
Running Cython-0.24.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dhfiv996\Cython-0.24.1\egg-dist-tmp-39sv6o4m
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 10, in run
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dhfiv996\Cython-0.24.1\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dhfiv996\Cython-0.24.1\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extensions
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 317, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 210, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 85, in _get_vc_env
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
  File "C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dhfiv996\Cython-0.24.1\setup.py", line 326, in <module>
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1064, in run_setup
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
  File "C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dhfiv996\Cython-0.24.1\setup.py", line 326, in <module>
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wa42hjf9\h5py\setup.py", line 149, in <module>
    cmdclass = CMDCLASS,
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 269, in __init__
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 827, in resolve
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1072, in best_match
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1084, in obtain
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 640, in easy_install
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 670, in install_item
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 850, in install_eggs
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
  File "c:\users\yaady\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1066, in run_setup
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Yaady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wa42hjf9\h5py\

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps:

- You need to install ***[`Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266)***.
- If you get error:

  > 'hdf5.h': No such file or directory

  Download the **`.whl`** file from ***[Python libs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)***

  - In my case it was ***`h5py‑2.7.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl`***
- Install **`.whl`** file using following command `python -m pip install <filename>.whl` [make sure **pip** is updated to latest version]

Additional instructions:
http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html